# GSAP text animation with mask color fails for alternate backgrounds

Tags: javascript, gsap, webflow

Greetings to everyone that's smarter than me,

As the title states, I know just enough to be dangerous. When things get complicated, I hide in the corner, crying.

The concept: animate text on the page as the user scrolls using GSAP in Webflow. I'm using the line mask option to reveal the text. This works for all the black text on a white background using a combo class.
[Example Text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6P4UJ.png)

The problem: I need to do the same thing for white text on a black background but I haven't been able to accomplish this.

I've tried using another script and/or variables but this is where my mentor (Google) and I hit the code wall.

The [website](https://jlp-bf31ff.webflow.io/). The ABOUT ME section is what I need to get up and running.

Below is the current script and libraries.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.12.1/gsap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.12.1/ScrollTrigger.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/split-type"></script>

<script>
gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger);

const splitTypes = document.querySelectorAll(".text-split");

splitTypes.forEach((char, i) => {
  const bg = "#F1F1F1";
  const fg = "#000000";

  const text = new SplitType(char, { types: "chars" });

  gsap.fromTo(
    text.chars,
    {
      color: bg
    },
    {
      color: fg,
      duration: 1,
      stagger: 1,
      opacity: 1,
      scrollTrigger: {
        trigger: char,
        start: "top 80%",
        end: "top 35%",
        scrub: true,
        markers: false,
        toggleActions: "play play reverse reverse"
      }
    }
  );
});
</script>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi there. I think the animation will almost be the same. All you need to change is the colors no? Maybe give one with a colored background a different class (.text-split.colored) or (.text-split.inverse) so you can select only the "black" ones and then you just change the color attribute for the animation. I guess you can have the from and to logic somewhere where it is shared (like write the config in a variable defaultFrom, defaultTo and then {...defaultTo, color: 'white'} so you only need to change the color. The rest is the same really.

Comment: Correct, the animation stays the same. I was thinking of using else/if statements but again, the code escapes me.